# Java: How can I prevent Canvas from being resized when it is added to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

When running this in my main:

```
    Canvas can = new Canvas();

    can.setSize(400, 400);

    System.out.print(can.getWidth() + ", " + can.getHeight() + " ");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(can);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println(can.getWidth() + ", " + can.getHeight());
```

The console reads:
400, 400
410, 410

It seems like when I add my Canvas to my JFrame and pack the JFrame it adds an extra 10 pixels to the width and height of my Canvas.  Is there any way I can prevent this from happening and get exactly a 400 by 400 Canvas?

Comment: Perhaps try a different layout manager. I think the default is FlowLayout. It could be doing this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a Canvas, that is an AWT component.

When using Swing you should use a `JPanel` and then override the `getPreferredSize()` of the panel to return the desired size.

Also, setSize() does nothing. The layout manager will determined the size of each component based on the rules of the layout manager.

Comment: Is overriding it a good idea? Isn't it still going to be a different size internally?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson, Well this is assuming you are doing custom painting and creating a custom component so the component should be responsible for determining its size. If of course you are just using the panel as a container for other Swing components, then you should let the layout manager determine its size.

Comment: Perfect. An informative answer that I can also use.